# Binary Less Replication in AEM

Tags: aem

As per my understanding when we want to share the particular part of author and publish,we use binary less replication. But what can be the use case,where i should use binary less replication.

I want to know the best practices of binary less replication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Binaryless replication or shared data store works on the basis that binaries are not copied across datastores. Only the metadata is replicated or transferred between the instances. The setup can be applied between authors and publishers. Alternatively data store can be shared between author instances also in a cold standby setup. It has 3 major use cases:

1. When you are dealing with very large DAM assets (high res images or videos), any replication involving binary copies over network is very costly. Binaryless is shared data store so binaries are not copied and you save on internal network traffic. It saves time and cost for some setup.
2. When you have lots of publishers, binary copy can bottleneck your author network. This reduces the load of that transfer and publishers can be scaled without impacting network usage exponentially.
3. TarMK cold standby has a limit of 2GB binary sync transfer across primary and standby standalone data stores. Binaryless (or shared datastore) is the only workaround for this limit.

For very large datastores you also save time in backups and restores as there is only one store as opposed to 2 stores for author and publishers.